# Split String with comma but not behind %

Tags: java, split

I want to split a string with comma but not the comma that behind %(whatever a key #,\,... etc).
Also print out "%" in output string.

Example 1:

```
String record="AA BBB %,CCC, 23, Female";
String[] outputString=record.split("[,[^%,]]");
```

**Output Format that I want to :**

```
AA BBB ,CCC
23
Female
```

Example 2:

```
String record="AA BBB %,CCC\%, 23, Female";
String[] outputString=record.split("[,[^%,]]");
```

**Output Format that I want to :**

```
AA BBB ,CCC%
23
Female
```

Comment: Su Mon ,Zaw is type or you want to drop %?

Comment: I would like to type "AA BBB ,CCC%" with escape key "%".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind

```
String[] outputString = record.split("(?<!%),\\s*");
for (int i = 0; i < outputString.length; i++)
    outputString[i] = outputString[i].replaceAll("%,", ",");
```

The `(?<!%)` returns causes the match to occur only if there not a % before the part that is matched.
The `\\s*` matches spaces after the comma so that you don't end up with spaces at the beginning of the string.
The for loop causes all `%,`s to be replaced by literal `,`s.

Comment: Thanks @McLovin ,it is worked for me.In addition,can I output without using `replaceAll("%,",",")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String record = "Su Mon %,Zaw, 23, Female";
String[] outputString = new String[20];
String current = "";
String previous = "";
int index = 0;
int start = 0;
int indexOfString = 0;

Pattern keywords = Pattern.compile("\%");//put your pattern here
while(index < record.length()) {
    current = record.substring(index,index);
    if(index > 0) {
        previous = record.substring(index-1, index);
    }
    if(current.equals(",") && !keywords.matcher(previous).matches()) {
        outputString[indexOfString] = record.substring(start, index);
        start = index;//update start to next index position
        indexOfString++;
    }
    index++;
}
```